# How to replace all matches with Regex / PHP / preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

basically I want to replace all words like : **test**, **someword**, **bleble** .

The problem is that regex I am using, only replaces one of the words, first one which is found . Can anyone help me with this one?

```
$string = 'http://nu/style/test/someword/bleble';
preg_replace('/(test|someword|bleble)/','',$string);
```

Best Regards,
Mateusz

Comment: So, see https://ideone.com/ArrsJz - it is removing them

Comment: So, what is the expected output?

Comment: I think, that your code works fine. Your code will output: `http://nu/style///`

Comment: Wiktor - Thanks. It seems that I have missed something in my URL. Problem is solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array to solve the problem.

```
$string  = "http://nu/style/test/someword/bleble";
$remove = array("/test/", "someword/", "bleble");

$result = str_replace($remove, ' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array()` for your patterns. You need one array for the patterns, which may be replaced and another array for replacements.

```
$string = 'http://nu/style/test/someword/bleble';
$patterns = array(
  "/test/",
  "/someword/",
  "/bleble/"
);

$replacements = array(
  "",
  "",
  ""
);

preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Of course, if you want to replace all the `$patterns` with the same word, you can use:

```
preg_replace($patterns, " ", $string);
```

> **OUTPUT:** `http://nu/style///`